# CHKDSK stuck on USN Journal

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

I ran a `chkdsk` on my failing 3TB WD Green and it's been 18 hours since it ran. It's now frozen on verifying the USN journal. See picture:

[image: chkdsk]

Seeing as it's frozen, can I unplug my hard drive?

Comment: I have seen chkdsk complete after over 2 days after it appeared to be stuck for a long long time so I would just wait a bit longer. You may want to check out https://trcdatarecovery.com/software-apps/chk-back

Comment: Can you interrupt with CTRL+C?

Comment: NVM, old topic.

Comment: I vote close, topic is so old there's virtually no chance we'll see additional info from original poster and community bot keeps promoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive may be damaged or severely riddled with errors, but unplugging it may not be the safest thing to do. I've had this problem before, where the chkdsk process was stuck at some point. I determined that my hard drive is damaged, and I had to replace it.

If it's genuinely stuck, try restarting into safe mode with command line and checking the disk in read only mode, if that also freezes, then I have nothing else for you except to bring it to an NCIX or some other computer store that can repair it, assuming you don't have life changing private data on it; if it does, and it can boot, I suggest backing it up ASAP and replacing it.